# comapare two array key using foreach inside foreach

Tags: php, foreach

i want to try foreach inside foreach.
this is my simple try:-

```
<?php
$a = array();
$a[0] = "a";
$a[1] = "b";
$a[2] = "y";
$a[3] = "z";
$b= array();
$b[0]=0;
$b[1]=1;
foreach ($a as $ak => $av) {
    foreach($b as $bk =>$bv)
    {
        if($ak == $bk)
        echo "match<br>";
    }
    echo "not match<br>";
}
?>
```

and this return output:-

```
match
not match
match
not match
not match
not match
```

but i want to:-

```
match
match
not match
not match
not match
not match
```

how can i got this type of o.p.
 
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel!

[array_diff_key](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php)

Answer (score 0):

keep result in array then sort

```
$a = array('a','b','y','z');
$b= array();
$res=array();
$b[0]=0;
$b[1]=1;
foreach ($a as $ak => $av) {
    foreach($b as $bk =>$bv)
    {
        if($ak == $bk)
        $res[]="match";
    }
    $res[]="not match";
}
sort($res);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($res);
```